# React Redux - Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, store

I need to find a way to get my data from my redux store into a map function but i end up with the error below

My console gives me for

```
setVariants(editProduct?.variants?.map((variant) => variant));
```

this:

```
[
0:{label: 'Small', price: '5', value: 0}
1: {label: 'Medium', price: '7.5', value: 1}
2: {label: 'Large', price: '10', value: 2}
]
```

But this code ends to be undefined

```
  const [variants, setVariants] = useState([
    { label: '', price: '', value: '' },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setVariants(editProduct?.variants?.map((variant) => variant));
  }, []);

  console.log(variants);
```

Thats why the code below ends to be:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')

```
 {variants.map((variant, index) => (
                      <div key={index} className=' mb-4'>
                        <div className='hidden'>{(variant.value = index)}</div>
                        <div>
                          <label className='block font-bold uppercase mb-2'>
                            <div className='flex'>
                              <div className='mr-2'>Variante {index + 1}</div>
                              <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
                                <svg
                                  onClick={() => handleAddVariants()}
                                  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                  class='h-5 w-5'
                                  viewBox='0 0 20 20'
                                  fill='currentColor'
                                >
                                  <path
                                    fill-rule='evenodd'
                                    d='M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm1-11a1 1 0 10-2 0v2H7a1 1 0 100 2h2v2a1 1 0 102 0v-2h2a1 1 0 100-2h-2V7z'
                                    clip-rule='evenodd'
                                  />
                                </svg>
                                <svg
                                  onClick={() => handleRemoveVariants(index)}
                                  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                  class='h-5 w-5'
                                  viewBox='0 0 20 20'
                                  fill='currentColor'
                                >
                                  <path
                                    fill-rule='evenodd'
                                    d='M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM7 9a1 1 0 000 2h6a1 1 0 100-2H7z'
                                    clip-rule='evenodd'
                                  />
                                </svg>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='flex'>
                              <input
                                className='mr-4 p-2 h-8 w-36 focus:outline-none bg-gray-700 border-b-2 border-yellow-500 font-semibold'
                                type='text'
                                name='label'
                                placeholder={'Name Variante ' + (index + 1)}
                                value={variant.label}
                                onChange={(event) =>
                                  handleVariantsChangeInput(index, event)
                                }
                              />

                              <input
                                className='h-8 w-16 p-2 focus:outline-none bg-gray-700 border-b-2 border-yellow-500 font-semibold'
                                type='number'
                                step='.01'
                                min='0'
                                name='price'
                                placeholder={'Preis ' + (index + 1)}
                                value={variant.price}
                                onChange={(event) =>
                                  handleVariantsChangeInput(index, event)
                                }
                              />
                              <div className='mt-1 font-semibold'>€</div>
                            </div>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))}
```

Edit

```
const initialVariants = [{ label: '', price: '', value: '' }];

const EditProduct = () => {...}
```

```
  const [variants, setVariants] = useState(initialVariants);

  console.log(variants);
  console.log(initialVariants);

  useEffect(() => {
    setVariants(
      editProduct?.variants?.map(
        (variant, value) =>
          ({
            ...variant,
            value,
          } ?? initialVariants)
      )
    );
  }, [editProduct]); // don't forget dependencies
```

Comment: _`{(variant.value = index)}`_  what is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: That's just for UI. It shows user Variant {index + 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```jsx
> <div className='hidden'>{(variant.value = index)}</div>
> ```

I have no idea what this is supposed to be doing but if you wanted to assign a `value` property from the index position, you should do that when you set the state value.

You should also provide a fallback value in case your optional chaining returns `undefined`

```js
const initialVariants = [{ label: "", price: "", value: "" }];
const [variants, setVariants] = useState(initialVariants);

useEffect(() => {
  setVariants(
    editProduct?.variants?.map((variant, value) => ({
      ...variant,
      value,
    })) ?? initialVariants
  );
}, [editProduct]); // don't forget dependencies
```

You can display the `value` (index) in your render without assigning

```jsx
{
  variants.map((variant) => (
    <div key={variant.value} className="mb-4">
      <div className="hidden">{variant.value}</div>
      {/* ... etc ... */}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Okay, the hidden one ill change i think thats not a big deal. it worked before but i think yours is the way it should be...  But my problem is still there with your initialVariant + useEffect i still end up with  "EditProduct.js:90 undefined" so i get for the map: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: @zuZuu there is no room in my answer for `variants` to ever be undefined.

Comment: Actually i kinda wonder how it is even possible with the nullish coalescing operator...

Comment: Haha yes i just came up with it :D I'll try to fix this there must be something wrong from my site

Comment: pls check my edit... i copied but if i console.log(variants) its undefined... console.log(initialVariants) shows me the initalVariants perfectly... so its some empty strings... i feel totaly stupid what am i doing wrong haha?

Comment: @zuZuu you've copied an older version of my code (my fault, I had a typo earlier)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the confusion